# Is possible to programmatically get invocation and recognition of any action from Google Home echo device?

Tags: android, echo, iot, google-home

I want to know when I speak any command to echo, whether it detects it or not? If it detects what is the exact command it detected?
for eg; If I say 'Hey Google, Increase volume on TV', Google Home echo will light up if it's in range and then perform the action. Is there any API so I will get to know echo is in range and it can listen.
Also what exactly it understood.

Comment: Search for an API or a SDK. https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/overview maybe?

Comment: Google Assistant Service requires to set up hardware, network access and register the device model. In my case I want to use my Google Home speaker as the device and want to get voice request response form it. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

In the `Google Home app`, go to your `profile` (top right corner), and select `My Activity`. You can then see when the Assistant was triggered for your account and which device this occurred on, as well as what was understood.

Comment: Thanks Toni.. I was looking for some API to get it.
We can use Accessibility Service to get this data.